# Why does Symfony recommend turning php_short_tags off

Tags: php, symfony, php-shorttags

I'm installing Symfony2 framework for the first time and the web config screen says to turn php short tags off. Is there any reason for this besides the arguments that in conflicts with xml or server incompatibility? Any issues specific to Symfony?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IMHO, feel free to enable short_open_tag if you prefer, and it is safe to ignore this warning issued by Symfony. Heck, I'd advocate removing the check entirely.

The two possible problems you cite are the only *theoretical* problems you might encounter from using short open tags, but in practice this never has been an issue to me in my 10 years developing PHP applications.

Even in XML-heavy application, it is unlikely you have an XML header parsed by PHP in more than a very few locations, and in those few occasions the problem is easily circumvented, by for example echoing the XML header itself. In this post-XHTML era, it is even more unlikely you'll be developing any web application with an XML header in a PHP template. A moot argument to begin with.

As far as the server configuration goes, even the average shared webhosting allows the PHP configuration to be modified these days, and this setting in particular can even be set at runtime in the remote possibility you can't. And who's deploying Symfony applications to a shared hosting anyway?

Short open tags need some loving, and they are getting some in PHP 5.4, where the echo syntax (`<?= ?>`) will be enabled regardless of the short_open_tag setting. Also, despite of what some might claim, short tags are in no way a deprecated PHP feature, and is here to stay.

If you use PHP templates, and prefer the short tags syntax, go for it!

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, there's nothing specific in Symfony 1 or 2 that will break if you use short tags, but speaking from personal experience, they're not worth the small amount of typing they save you. You mention two valid complaints - XML conflicts and server incompatibility. Those are reason enough not to use them. Moving projects from one server to another and having to replace short tags is an annoying waste of time :)

Comment: what conflicts you are talking about?

Comment: Well after moving on to the next page of the intro, I realized that symfony uses its own templating system. So I guess using php short tags isn't really used anyway? Correct?

Comment: I guess the twig template engine is optional.

Comment: Symfony still supports PHP templates next to Twig templates, and short tags look a lot tidier in templates imho. The XML header problem is easily resolved (and how many XML templates parsed by PHP do you have in a typical Symfony application anyway?), and I cannot believe you would be deploying a Symfony2 project to a server on which you don't have control on the php.ini these days. Also, short tags are getting the love they deserve in PHP 5.4 and the <?= ?> syntax will be enabled regardless of the short_open_tag setting.

Comment: some discussion about stuff breaking in 1.2 in comments at http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-1-2-error-templates-and-request-formats

Comment: 2.0 coding standards forbid using short tags, if you're thinking contrib http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/contributing/code/standards.html#structure

Comment: @yitznewton the example is coding standards for a class and not for a template. It would only make sense to use shortags in a template IMO.

Comment: @yitznewton also under the discussion about stuff breaking. Quote from Fabien "@Zoltan Lajos Kis: I have changed XML templates to also work when short_tags are on."

Comment: @dardub true, but still "Never use short tags" to me implies templates or otherwise. So contribs would do well to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's **never** a good idea to use `short_tags` mostly because of server incompatibility.

**Server Incompatibility**

Not every PHP server has `short_tags` enabled. So if you use short tags anywhere in a project, and someday in the future it happens to be put on a server with short tags disabled, your site is now broken. You have to either go through your code and find/replace or enable short tags on the server, which you might not have the authority to do anyways.

**Symfony**

Symfony makes several **Best Practice** suggestions. They are not necessarily things that will make or break development using Symfony, but they are good practices that many professional developers follow. Not using `short_tags` is a good thing to put into practice.

Anyways, all short tags really does is save you from having to type a few extra characters every now and then. If you are really that concerned about typing extra characters, you should really be using an IDE or Text Editor that supports snippets, like [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

Comment: I just feel like it makes the php template look much cleaner than having to use <?php echo '' ?>. Why not try to move forward with improving php rather than hindering it for minor issues that can easily be solved.

Comment: The issue might not be as easy to change deep in the PHP code as you might think.

Comment: I meant that the complications you mention such as server compatibility can usually easily be solved by editing php.ini.

Comment: In a shared web server environment, this would not be favorable, as making core PHP changes could cause unexpected problems with other customer's websites. In the case where you are running your own server and are in full control of Apache and PHP, then by all means, go with the short codes. But my original point was that you never really know exactly what kind of server your site might be required to run on someday, especially when developing sites for a business or customer. It's good practice to code the site to be as flexible as virtually possible so you don't have to fix things later.

Comment: @Jakobud short_open_tag can be set even on a .htaccess or run-time level, where in no way it would impact other user's accounts in a shared hosting environment.

Comment: @Gerry that is a good point. Also this answer is becoming more and more outdated as PHP 5.4 is becoming the standard more and more places and 5.4 supports short tags by default.